# Why don't we know the exact equations of string theory?

Tags: string-theory

I have read in Brian Greene's book "The Elegant Universe" that so far physicists don't know the exact equations of string theory, and they have to use approximations of those equations and get approximate solutions. But how come? Surely, although the solutions may be approximate, we should be able to get the exact equations? Maybe I am just too naive in string theory. Can someone explain this to me?

---

A quote from *The Elegant Universe* along these lines:

> Briefly put, the equations of string theory are so complicated that no one knows their exact form. Physicists have managed to write down only approximate versions of the equations. It is these approximate equations that differ significantly from one string theory to the next. And it is these approximate equations, within the context of any one of the five string theories, that gives rise to an abundance of solutions, a cornucopia of unwanted universes.

> Since 1995 (the start of the second superstring revolution), there has been a growing body of evidence that the exact equations, whose precise form is still beyond our reach, they resolve these problems, thereby helping to give string theory the stamp of inevitability. In fact, it has already been established to the satisfaction of most string theorists that, when the exact equations are understood, it will show that all five string theories are actually intimately related.

(It may also be worth noting that *The Elegant Universe* was first published in 1999.)

Comment: You should give an exact quote, to see the context for the statement.

Comment: In general, the "equations of string theory" could refer to a bunch of different things. Definitely needs context to attempt to clarify.

Comment: I have edited your question to include what I think is a pertinent quote from Greene's book;  please feel free to roll back the change if it's not what you're referring to.  (There's also a quote along these lines in the preface, but I think this one gives more context;  I kind of know what he's referring to in that quote, but I'll leave it to the experts to explain it fully.)